# Core Data was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I've an annoying problem with Core Data. My app need to get contacts from iPhone and save it in my database. I'm trying to do that in background thread.

**I use above code for that:**

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(fetchingContact) withObject:nil];


    -(void)fetchingContact{
    // Some Code
    for (int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++)
    {
    //Some Code
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [APP_DELEGATE managedObjectContext];
        ABRecordID recordID = ABRecordGetRecordID(person);
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(contactId = '%d')",recordID]];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
        NSError *error = nil;
//crash
        NSArray *contactObjArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
//crash
        if (error) {}
        Contact *contacts;
        if (contactObjArray.count == 0) {
            contacts = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        }else {
            contacts = [contactObjArray objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    //Some Code
    }
    }
```

**In AppDelegate:**

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
     NSLog(@"managedObjectContext");
    // Returns ;the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.)
     if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
          return _managedObjectContext;
     }

     NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
     if (!coordinator) {
          return nil;
     }
     _managedObjectContext =  [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]initWithConcurrencyType: NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
     [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
     return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

Here I try to save in my `Core Data` but it crash with error :

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x15fad880> was mutated while being enumerated.'` at this line:

```
 NSArray *contactObjArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

I search already online, I found a lot of things but nothing helps me. When I run that, there is no place where Core Data is changed, or Contact entity. That does this error very strange.

If I run it in main thread I get no errors/ no crash, but if the app is quit in that time (while is executed) I lose all content from `Contact`

Please, any help. Tell me if I need to provide more information.

Comment: Which line does it throw the exception on?  set an exception breapoint

Comment: I just make an edit. Sorry, i forget to speciefied the line.  i don't get the crash everytime. It is spontaneous, can crash at contact 150,200, 300...

Comment: Check the result of executeFetchRequest with contactObjArray == nil, then check the error.  Also the [NSString stringWithFormat: ...] argument is unnecessary with [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: ]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error happen when you are modifying core data while you try to get them.

That also could be cause of the loop you're doing, you are inserting a new object in coredata without saving before you do an other retrieve. Try saving your managedobjectcontext :

favorite
I have an annoying problem with Core Data. My app need to get contacts from iPhone and save it in my database. I'am trying to do that in background thread.

I use above code for that:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(fetchingContact) withObject:nil];


-(void)fetchingContact{
// Some Code
for (int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++)
{
//Some Code
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [APP_DELEGATE managedObjectContext];
    ABRecordID recordID = ABRecordGetRecordID(person);
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(contactId = '%d')",recordID]];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *contactObjArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (error) {}
    Contact *contacts;
    if (contactObjArray.count == 0) {
        contacts = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [context save:&error];
    }else {
        contacts = [contactObjArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }
//Some Code
}
}
```

If that doesn't solve your problem, maybe check if your method is called multiple times.