# Core Data Error - very random

Tags: ios, swift, runtime-error

I know this post has similar other posts but nothing I've found so far has been able to solve my problem. I am receiving data from an API via JSON and saving it, then displaying the data to the UI via a Core Data retrieve, after the saving. About every 100 or so searches (API calls), this happens. The number between 1 and 100 is random. Sometimes it's every 20 searches, etc. Newer installations of the app seem to have this issue more.

```
Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is 
usually a bug within an observer of 
NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  *** Collection 
<__NSCFSet: 0x6000030e7f60> was mutated while being enumerated. with 
userInfo (null)

CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during 
Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer 
of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  *** Collection 
<__NSCFSet: 0x6000030e7f60> was mutated while being enumerated. with 
userInfo (null)

2018-06-30 12:51:36.264733-0600 [7055:6252340] *** 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 
'*** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x6000030e7f60> was mutated while being 
enumerated.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d829f66 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c8f904d objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d826c6c __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 124
3   CoreData                            0x000000010d1baf28 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processDeletedObjects:] + 328
4   CoreData                            0x000000010d1a529d -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _propagatePendingDeletesAtEndOfEvent:] + 109
5   CoreData                            0x000000010d1a028a -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 1034
6   CoreData                            0x000000010d1790ff _performRunLoopAction + 335
7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d78cea7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d7872de __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430
9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d787981 __CFRunLoopRun + 1553
10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d787031 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
11  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000110d35136 GSEventRunModal + 62
12  UIKitCore                           0x0000000116098839 UIApplicationMain + 140
13  AppNameHere                         0x00000001063c7234 main + 68
14  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010eed2a61 start + 1
)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
2018-06-30 12:51:36.271149-0600 [7055:6255838] [Assert] 
Cannot be called with asCopy = NO on non-main thread.
```

Posted is some simplified code (removing some stuff not specific to CoreData, for easier reading here. I already know that a lot of this code is bad form, however this is my best work and trying hard.

```
//globalVariable declared:
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
//in AppDelegate:
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "AppName")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
//in VC:
let downloadAirports = DownloadAirports()
let initialAirportDownload = defaults.bool(forKey: "initialAirportDownload")
if initialAirportDownload == false   {
    self.showAirportDownloadingAlert(show: true)
    self.downloadAirports.getAirports(completion: {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("finishedDownloadingAirports")
            self.defaults.set(true, forKey: "initialAirportDownload")
            self.showAirportDownloadingAlert(show: false)
        })
    }
}

//in DownloadAirports class:
struct AirportsJSON : Decodable {
    let airports : [AirportJSON]
}
struct AirportJSON : Decodable {
    let iata : String?
    let airportName : String?
    let countryCode : String?
    let utcOffset : Int?
    let classification : Int?
}

func getAirports(completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let serverAddress = ServerAccess.serverAddress
    let jsonUrlString = "\(serverAddress)"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {
        return
    }

    deleteAirports()

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }
        do {
            let airports = try JSONDecoder().decode(AirportsJSON.self, from: data)
            guard let moc = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else {
                return
            }
            var i = 0
            while i < airports.airports.count {
                self.saveAirport(airports: airports.airports[i], moc: moc)
                i += 1
            }
        } catch let jsonErr {
            print(jsonErr)
        }
        completion()
        }.resume()
    guard let moc = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else {
        return
    }
    do {
        try moc.save()
    } catch {
        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func saveAirport(airports : AirportJSON, moc : NSManagedObjectContext) {
    var searchString = ""
    let airport = Airports(context: moc)
    if let iata = airports.iata {
        if let name = airports.airportName {
            searchString = "\(iata) - \(name)"
            airport.searchString = searchString
            airport.iata = iata
            print(iata)
        }
    }
    if let classification = airports.classification {
        airport.classification = Int16(classification)
    }
    if let timeZone = airports.utcOffset {
        airport.timeZone = Int16(timeZone)
    }
    if let countryCode = airports.countryCode {
        airport.countryCode = countryCode
    }
}

func deleteAirports() {
    guard let moc = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else {
        return
    }
    let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Airports> = Airports.fetchRequest()
    do {
        let airports = try moc.fetch(fetchRequest)
        for airport in airports {
            moc.delete(airport)
        }
        do {
            try moc.save()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share some code also ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Core Data was mutated while being enumerated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38434129/core-data-was-mutated-while-being-enumerated)

Comment: Have you figured out what line in your code is causing the error? If it is always the same one that ends up in the StackTrace then you should show it. If it isn't you will have to investigate more (or share more code). StackOverflow is not a guessing site. People will help you by making sense of your code and  pointing out bugs, but they cannot do so if you do not share what you are doing (exactly).

Comment: Sorry the delay, I have not figured out when line is causing this yet as it just points to AppDelegate SIGABRT during the crash. I will post some code structure soon.