# App getting crashed while fetching data from core data swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Here is the full code for fetch data.
Here is the code of fetching data from core data. What is the problem here? Please help what is wrong in fetching data

```
static func getChatMessagesForGroup( groupId : Double) -> [GroupConversationMessage]{
    AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().log.debug("\(groupId)")
    let managedContext = CoreDataHelper.getNSMangedObjectContext()

    var messages = [GroupConversationMessage]()
    var conversationObjects = [NSManagedObject]()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: GROUP_CONVERSATION_TABLE_NAME)
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(GroupConversationMessage.FLD_GROUP_ID) = %@", argumentArray: [StringUtils.getStringFromDouble(decimalNumber : groupId)])
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: GroupConversationMessage.FLD_TIME, ascending: true)
    var sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor]()
    sortDescriptors.append(sortDescriptor)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors =  sortDescriptors
    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
        do {
            let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            conversationObjects = results as! [NSManagedObject]
        } catch let error as NSError {
            AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().log.error("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }

   for i in 0 ..< conversationObjects.count  {
        let message = GroupConversationMessage()
        message.uniqueID = conversationObjects[i].value(forKey: QuickRideMessageEntity.UNIQUE_ID) as? String
        message.id = conversationObjects[i].value(forKey: GroupConversationMessage.FLD_ID) as! Double
        message.groupId = conversationObjects[i].value(forKey: GroupConversationMessage.FLD_GROUP_ID) as! Double
        message.senderId = conversationObjects[i].value(forKey: GroupConversationMessage.FLD_SENDER_ID) as! Double
        message.senderName = conversationObjects[i].value(forKey: GroupConversationMessage.FLD_SENDER_NAME) as? String
        message.message = (conversationObjects[i].value(forKey: GroupConversationMessage.FLD_MESSAGE) as! String)
        message.time = conversationObjects[i].value(forKey: GroupConversationMessage.FLD_TIME) as! Double
        messages.append(message)
    }
    return messages
}
```

Comment: What is crash error ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya This is the crash message which occurs Fatal Exception: NSGenericException
*** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x107626b10> was mutated while being enumerated.

Comment: If you changed any entity you need to reinstall app.

Comment: Did you check similar question in stackoverflow  like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38434129/core-data-was-mutated-while-being-enumerated

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I had checked that post but it dint help

Comment: Try to put that in main thread. look like multiple thread is modifying coredata as it is not thread safe !!

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya you mean dispatch.main.async{}

Comment: Yes try to add your code in that block

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya if I try to put that code it shows an error like :- Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '() throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '@convention(block) () -> Void'

Comment: How is the fetch request created? This code doesn't seem to be the cause of the exception. It's more likely related to a Core Data relationship.

Comment: can u post your full code so that it will be clear what exactly you are doing ? also can you give at which line it crash ?

Comment: @vivekDas Full code is pasted in the question

Comment: Now just comment your bottom for loop and try to run the code is it works ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you are trying to update or save while fetching the data or maybe your collection type might be immutable and you are trying to mutate it.